# Sequelize failing to connect, error displays windows username instead of supplied username

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Hi I am having some issue connecting sequelize to my postgres database. I have successfully used node pg and pg promise before, but this is the first time I have used sequelize and I think I am missing some fundamental concept.

I am running my postgres server in a docker container if that matters.

I have set up to test like this:

```
//Imports required modules 
require("dotenv").config();

//Imports required modules
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

//Sets up database connection
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'postgres',
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
});

const testFunction = async function(){
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

testFunction();

module.exports = {sequelize};
```

Unfortunately when I run the code I am getting an error referring to my windows username instead of the username I provide.

```
ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: password authentication failed for user "my_windows_username"
```

I have checked all of my env variables and all should be correct as I set up the database.  What am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure `process.env.DB_USER` is set?  What if you `console.log(process.env.DB_USER)`?

Comment: @richyen Hi, yes it is definitely set. I have tried logging all the env variables to the console and they all display exactly as expected. Very odd! I don't understand why it is grabbing my windows username either.

Comment: try `username: process.env.DB_USER` instead of `user: process.env.DB_USER`?

Comment: @richyen Just tried, it gives a similar but different error "ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: database "my_database" does not exist

Comment: sounds like you'll need to see what the value of `process.env.DB_NAME` is and whether it actually exists at the cluster found in `process.env.DB_HOST`

Comment: @richyen DB_name matches what I used when creating the docker container, DB_host is set to localhost. How can I check if it exists at the cluster?

Comment: oh if you're using docker, I think you need to update the question to include the relevant information -- docker puts a different twist in this discussion for sure

Comment: @richyen Okay, when using the same variables with node pg and pg promise I have been able to access the database in other projects. But when using sequalize I get this error. I'm hosting the container locally and have my host variable is set to localhost. What other info would be useful?

Comment: if the database is living on your local machine (the host machine that runs docker), then you need to set `host` to the hostname of that host machine, not `localhost` -- if you have it set as `localhost`, then the container running sequelize will look in the container for the database, not the host machine

Comment: @richyen First thanks so much for taking the time to puzzle through this with me. I have docker running on my local machine, the same machine trying to run the test script to connect with sequalizer. I used localhost as the host when connecting "node pg promise" to a database using the same docker configuration with no problem. I thought that both sequalizer and pg-promse use node pg as their engine, so I can't figure out why it works with one and not the other. If I don't use localhost what should I be using. Sorry I am so new to these operations kinds of things!

Comment: @richyen And to clarify I do not have the script running in a docker container, it is just running on my local machine, only the database is in its own container.

Comment: hmm so if i understand correctly, you have the script running on your host machine (for the sake of this discussion, let's just say it's your laptop).  The database is running inside docker, and docker is running on the laptop.  In order to connect to the database within docker, you'll need to make sure (with `docker ps -a`) that the port is exposed.   You'll tell the script to use `localhost` and the port you found in the `docker ps -a` output -- does that work?

Comment: @richyen That is all exactly right and how I have it set, but it's still giving me that error, very weird! I checked docker ps-a and it shows  the port as 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, I have my port in sequalizer set to 5432. Maybe I will just try building the server out a little more and this will end up fixing itself. It's just so odd, I had this issue with pg promise too, but ended up resolving it by running postgres in docker instead, but I don't remember the details of why that made a difference, oops!